# How do I install older programs located on older ISO distros?

Tags: software-installation, sles, yast

Linux distro: SLES 11 SP4

I have on hand SLES 11 ISO's: SP1, SP2, & SP3

I need to locate and install older programs located on older ISO's.

For example: I have gcc 4.7 on SP4, but I need to install gcc 4.3.4 on SP1.

When I insert the disc(s) into the DVD-ROM, I open YaST > Software Management > Search: gcc > The only thing I see is the SP4 catologue list, but I'm fairly certain that the gcc versions are located on those ISO's.

What am I doing wrong and how can I install older programs from previous SP packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through trial and error, I learned that by right clicking on the DVD icon on my desktop > Selecting "COPY DISC" > Select the option to ISO.

Once I have created the ISO I can then go to YaST > Software Management > Configuration > Repositories > Add the ISO to the repository list to search the catalog of program files to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

If it were just GCC, you could just build it from source. Keep that in mind should you ever lose your discs or need a version you don't currently have.